# Is there anyway to run visualizations with Pandora Radio?

Tags: pandora

On a PC, is there anyway to run visualizations with Pandora Radio.  I realized Pandora itself does not have visualizations, but is there some way to rig it up with another piece of software?

Answer (score 1):

You can use use Winamp's visualizations, by configuring Pandora's output to plug into line-in, it should work.

Detailed steps at [Winamp forums](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?s=&threadid=64973)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create your own stand-alone visualizer that will work with either Pandora or Spotify. I have mine hooked to a 4K TV. This is a Mac approach, but can be done with Windows. https://mhd.tips/spotify-visualizer-medium